# How can i solve the TypeError gotten while working with feature_engine

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

I am working with feature_engine to fill missing values

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# from feature-engine
from feature_engine import missing_data_imputers as mdi

#Working with House Data and Feature Engine__Practice
cols_to_use = [
    'BsmtQual', 'FireplaceQu', 'LotFrontage', 'MasVnrArea', 'GarageYrBlt',
]
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Hash\kaggle\Housing Project/train.csv', usecols=cols_to_use)
```

I created an instance of mdi to fit my data

```
imputer = mdi.MeanMedianImputer(imputation_method='median')
imputer.fit(data)
```

But on calling the transform method it returns a TypeError of which i cant find a reason why it happened.

```
tmp = imputer.transform(data)
```

Here is the error returned

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-2f486acb96bd> in <module>
----> 1 tmp = imputer.transform(data)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\feature_engine\missing_data_imputers.py in transform(self, X)
    103     # Ugly work around to import the docstring for Sphinx, otherwise none of this is necessary
    104     def transform(self, X):
--> 105         X = super().transform(X)
    106         return X
    107 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\feature_engine\base_transformers.py in transform(self, X)
     35 
     36         # Check method fit has been called
---> 37         check_is_fitted(self)
     38 
     39         # check that input is a dataframe

TypeError: check_is_fitted() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attributes'
```

Comment: which variables type are ['BsmtQual', 'FireplaceQu', 'LotFrontage', 'MasVnrArea', 'GarageYrBlt'] ?. By checking the documentation, when you not specify the variables parameter to MedianMedianImputer, it selects all variables of type numeric. Perhaps, your variables need to be transformed to numeric.

Comment: Like you said, feature_engine automatically picks numeric values of which when I use imputed.vatiables to check features that have been selected, all are numeric features. So that shouldn't be a reason why it ain't working. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the stack trace you provided, this seems to me like an incompatibility between `feature_engine` and an old version of scikit-learn. In older versions (e.g. [0.21](https://scikit-learn.org/0.21/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html)), `attributes` was a mandatory parameter for `check_is_fitted`, but in newer versions (e.g. [0.23](https://scikit-learn.org/0.23/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html)) it is optional:

> If `None`, `estimator` is considered fitted if there exist an attribute that ends with a underscore and does not start with double underscore.

Comment: Like you said Shovalt, it was a version error. I uninstalled the feature_engine and installed again and to worked fine. Thanks

Comment: yep. That incompatibility has been taken care of already and the error should not appear any more :)